# Functions work seperately but cannot compose together

Tags: javascript

I'm trying a very simple program to understand composing functions in JavaScript.

```js
// This compose comes from web
const compose = (...fns) => x => fns.reduceRight((v, f) => f(v), x);

const array = 'array'

const actionCreator = (type, payload) => {
   return {
      type,
      payload
   }
};
const log = object => {
   console.log(object)
};
// This works
log(actionCreator(array, [1,2,3,4]));
// This does not
compose(log, actionCreator)(array, [1,2,3,4]);
```

For some reasons, calling log(actionCreator) works, and it logs`{type: 'array', payload: [1,2,3,4]}`. But calling compose keeps logging`{type: 'array', payload: undefined}`. And it's not just an array. Regardless of what the second argument after array is, the payload is always undefined, whether it's a string, a number...But somehow it stills knows type, only payload is undefined So is there something I did wrong. It's so simple, it should not have these kinds of bugs. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Your `compose()` function returns a function that expects one argument, but you call it with two.

Comment: In the inner function of compose you're expecting one argument `x` but you're sending two `array, [1,2,3,4]`

Comment: Can you suggest a way to fix this, maybe compose should stay the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust your `compose()` function:

```
const compose = (...fns) => (...args) => 
    fns.reduceRight((v, f, i) => (i !== fns.length - 1) ? f(v) : f(...args), null);
```

That will use the list of provided arguments for the *first* function, and then behave as `.reduceRight` normally behaves for the rest, using the return value of the previous iteration as the input value for the next.

The `.reduceRight()` is started with `null` as the input because the first iteration won't use that.

*edit* — here's a simpler version:

```
const compose = (...fns) => (...args) => fns.reduceRight((v, f) => f(v), fns.pop()(...args));
```

That one uses the last function applied to the arguments as the initial value for the `.reduceRight()`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works!

Comment: I'm sorry but it seems I'm mistaken. It's not working, you have unused v in your code, is there something wrong with that?

Comment: @FreeMe you're right, hold on....

Comment: @FreeMe ok I misunderstood, will update shortly

Comment: @FreeMe check the update

Comment: Ok. Will tell you if there's any problem. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It´s clear that your compose function expects "x" but you are passing "(array, [1,2,3,4])" so in fact "x" becomes the first param which is "array", but the second param is undefined cause you are not passing it to the initial value of the accumulator

Comment: I see. So what should I change, the actionCreator, or compose itself